# How to deal with warnings about tail-padded arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, warnings

I'm writing a C++ application which uses a C library that defines a tail-padded structure in one of its headers. Without going into too much details, it looks somewhat like this:

```
struct MyStruct {

    // ... other members

    // The last member, a tail-padding array
    MyType myBuffer[];
}
```

I use `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror` with `g++` and `-std=c++0x`.

Unfortunately, `g++` gives me a warning about that array:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids zero-size array 'myBuffer' [-Wpedantic]
```

What is the right way to deal with this?

I know I can suppress the warning by adding a `pragma` to the header myself:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wpedantic"
```

But that doesn't feel right. What do you guys suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You could

- Remove the zero-sized array.
- Build without `-Wpedantic` (possibly only for that file).
- Build without `-Werror` and ignore the warning.
- Build the code as C.

Comment: It is still not valid C++. What about compiling C code as C code?